# RegExp pattern to find words

Tags: regex

I know this seems a duplicated question but I can't find what I need.

I want to make a TextView (Android) where each word is clickable, but I need to match **every sequence of characters** unless whitespaces, so something like "hello!" or *"«tomorrow"* or *"días"* are valid matches for me.

So I don't need the pattern to find whitespaces, because I don't want split.

My scenario is Android but I only need the regexp, I'm playing with http://regexr.com/ to test and one example text to test is:

> Con cien cañones por banda, viento en popa a toda vela, no corta el
>   mar, sino vuela, un velero bergantín: bajel pirata que llaman por su
>   bravura el Temido, en todo mar conocido del uno al otro confín. La
>   luna en el mar riela, en la lona gime el viento, y alza en blando
>   movimiento olas de plata y azul; y ve el capitán pirata, cantando
>   alegre en la popa, Asia a un lado, al otro Europa y allá a su frente
>   Stambul. «Navega, velero mío, sin temor, que ni enemigo navío, ni
>   tormenta, ni bonanza, tu rumbo a torcer alcanza, ni a sujetar tu
>   valor. «Veinte presas hemos hecho a despecho del inglés, y han rendido
>   sus pendones cien naciones a mis pies. «¿Qué es mi barco? Mi tesoro.
>   ¿Qué es mi Dios? La libertad. ¿Mi ley? ¡La fuerza y el viento! ¿Mi
>   única patria? ¡La mar! «Allá muevan feroz guerra ciegos reyes por un
>   palmo más de tierra: que yo tengo aquí por mío cuanto abarca el mar
>   bravío, a quien nadie impuso leyes. «Y no hay playa sea cual quiera,
>   ni bandera de esplendor, que no sienta mi derecho y dé pecho a mi
>   valor. «¿Qué es mi barco? Mi tesoro. ¿Qué es mi Dios? La libertad. ¿Mi
>   ley? ¡La fuerza y el viento! ¿Mi única patria? ¡La mar! «A la voz de
>   «¡barco viene!» Es de ver cómo vira y se previene a todo trapo a
>   escapar: que yo soy el rey del mar, y mi furia es de temer. «En las
>   presas yo divido lo cogido por igual: sólo quiero por riqueza la
>   belleza sin rival. «¿Qué es mi barco? Mi tesoro. ¿Qué es mi Dios? La
>   libertad. ¿Mi ley? ¡La fuerza y el viento! ¿Mi única patria? ¡La mar!
>   «¡Sentenciado estoy a muerte! Yo me río: no me abandone la suerte, y
>   al mismo que me condena, colgaré de alguna antena, quizá en su propio
>   navío. «Y si caigo, ¿qué es la vida? Por perdida ya la di cuando el
>   yugo del esclavo, como un bravo, sacudí. «¿Qué es mi barco? Mi tesoro.
>   ¿Qué es mi Dios? La libertad. ¿Mi ley? ¡La fuerza y el viento! ¿Mi
>   única patria? ¡La mar! «Son mi música mejor aquilones; el estrépito y
>   temblor de los cables sacudidos, del negro mar los bramidos y el rugir
>   de mis cañones. «Y del trueno al son violento, y del viento al
>   rebramar, yo me duermo sosegado. Arrullado por el mar. «¿Qué es mi
>   barco? Mi tesoro. ¿Qué es mi Dios? La libertad. ¿Mi ley? ¡La fuerza y
>   el viento! ¿Mi única patria? ¡La mar!

Comment: Your example would be matched by [\wñáúéí]+ ... i guess you need some more lettersbut i think you can get the point

Comment: @JochenSchultz I hope you agree with me that add any UTF-8 character to a regexp expression doesn't seems to be a good solution, but maybe I'm to newbie with regexp and is the only solution, there is no better approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have almost answered your question by yourself.

"Every sequence of characters unless whitespaces" - it is exactly `/([^\s])+/g`

Comment: I had go with `/\S+/g` if it's supported (negation of \s). Worth noting \s match space, tabs, carriage return, linefeed and newline.

Comment: [`\S` is supported](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern.html). More, there is an answer to the question on that page (`\\S+` is used in a `replaceAll` though).

Comment: Thanks Andy, I know would be an easy one, but I can assure you that it was difficult find the answer there, too easy question that normally is answered with a .split sentence.

Comment: @stribizhev and Tensibai in my scenario I will never have this special characters because text is procesed before I need to filter it. Btw, thx for the suggestion I'll take into account for future needs